# What this element ending with ":" in the code means?

Tags: c, syntax

I encountered this part of code which I am not able to understand:

```
    } else if(ev != PROCESS_EVENT_POLL) {
     continue;
}

again:   //What this line do?

u = NULL;

for(t = timerlist; t != NULL; t = t->next) {
```

The line `again:` is the one that bothers me. Any explanation would be welcome.

Comment: You don't know `goto` in C?

Comment: If you don't know yet, you're' all good. No need to learn. :-) [_NO hard feelings, @i486_]

Comment: One of the worst things you could include in structured programming... GOTOs

Comment: Ok I quit learning C language Sourav :D

Answer (score 7):

This `again:` is called a `label`. They are essentially used as *markers* for certain position of code. They do not affect the code flow by themselves.

To quote the `C11` standard, chapter §6.8.1, *Labeled statements*, the general syntax is

> `labeled-statement:`
>
> > > > `identifier : statement`
> > > >
> > > > **case** `constant-expression : statement`
> > > >          **default** : `statement`

Where `case` and `default` are two *predefined* and reserved label names, used for special purpose.

Also, regarding the **Semantics**,

> Any statement may be preceded by a prefix that declares an identifier as a label name. Labels in themselves do not alter the flow of control, which  continues unimpeded across them.

- One most commonly [*mis(?)*]used  scenario: with `goto`.
- One widely used but less-noticed scenario: with `switch` statement.

Comment: A label for `switch` statement is defined with a `case` keyword, and it's not an arbitrary identifier but rather a constant expression evaluating to a possible value of the switch expression. Yes, it is also called 'a label' but NO, it has NOTHING in common with the label discussed here (except the terminating colon). [Edit: switch-lables without a `case`-like keyword are used in Pascal, IIRC, not in C.]

Comment: @CiaPan So you mean to say, `case`/ `default` is not a label in `C`? IMHO, `case` itself is not a constant expression, right?

Comment: @CiaPan The language specification calls them labels, and they act like labels, except that you can't `goto` them.

Answer (score 3):

It's a label in the code. One that can be used with a GOTO.

```
goto labelname;
label: //stuff
```

Answer (score 0):

As others explained, the word followed with a colon is a label, serving as a destination point for a `goto` jump.

The `continue` keyword visible in second line indicates this is a part of some loop. In this context the word chosen for a label ('*again*') suggests it's a starting point for partial re-iteration (a full re-iteration would be most probably done with `continue`).